# Expand accordion containing active link as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Okay so I have seen lots of accordion examples out there - some are extremely complex and some really simple.

I have just been looking for a quick simple accordion menu in JQuery and I have found one that is almost perfect.

My accordion contains 3 headings (product categories) and each contain a number of links.

```
<div class="sideNav">
    <!--Accordion Menu 1-->
    <h3 class="js_accordion-button">First Category</h3>
    <ul class="js_accordion-content">
        <li><a href="/product1">Stickers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product2">Oranges</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product3">Bananas</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Accordion Menu 2-->
    <h3 class="js_accordion-button">Second Category</h3>
    <ul class="js_accordion-content">
        <li><a href="/product10">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product11">Lemon</a></li>
        <li><a href="/product12">Cheese</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.js_accordion-button').on('click',function() {
            jQuery('.js_accordion-content').slideUp('fast');
            jQuery(this).next('.js_accordion-content').slideDown('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you were to navigate to the stickers page currently the accordion menu would be all closed on the left.

What I want to happen is it to open the accordion menu that contains the active page link as default.

Comment: Do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/865/?

Comment: Kind of like that - but I want to dynamically set the ul menu to active if it contains an href that matches the URL.